# Advantage of async/await over blocking in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await

Modern unit tests frameworks support awaiting the results of an asychronous unit test, like this:

```
public async Task SomeTest()
{
    var result = await SomeMethodAsync();
    // ... Verify the result ...
}
```

Is there any advantage of using this async approach over simply blocking?

```
public void SomeTest()
{
    var result = SomeMethodAsync().Result;
    // ... Verify the result ...
}
```

Does the async only provide a benefit when running tests in parallel?

Comment: The fact that Main thread for an automates test suite is free to execute more unit tests in parallel, does that sound like an advantage, instead of being blocked at a synchronous call

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary benefits of `async` code are a responsive UI on the client side, and scalability on the server side. For unit tests, you get a bit of scalability (which translates to overall speed benefits since unit tests are bursted by nature).

But it's not a huge benefit. Your tests would (probably) run a bit faster.

I usually use `async Task` unit test methods for these reasons:

- If you're testing code within a context, then blocking can cause the classic deadlock problem. Note that some frameworks (e.g., xUnit) always provide a context by default. Even for other frameworks, it's often necessary to provide a context to unit test ViewModels.
- `await` doesn't wrap exceptions in `AggregateException`.
- You do get a bit of a scalability benefit which (in theory) allows your unit tests to run faster overall. Assuming your framework runs your tests in parallel.
- Why not? They're just as easy as synchronous methods. `async Task` unit tests methods have been supported by every major unit test framework since 2012.

Comment: All good and +1. But regarding "Why not": You now can't pause the debugger and see where an IO bound test is stopped (maybe even hanging) at that point in time.

Comment: @usr Msft is working on that feature(or planned. Not sure where I saw that). Hope we'll be having a debugger window which shows the outstanding await points

Comment: @SriramSakthivel nice, profiling is also a pain point. I'm not aware of any profiler that works with async IO.

Comment: Oh, and code coverage. It's usually thrown off, too. But that would be the case whether the unit test methods were async or sync.

Comment: Another "Why not": If you're using NCrunch the "hotspots" are not displaying the actual duration with async calls, see https://ncrunch.uservoice.com/forums/245203-feature-requests/suggestions/16740094-enable-hotspots-indicators-also-for-awaited-asyn , thus if your test method has a lot of awaits you won't be able to tell the bottle necks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any advantage of using this async approach over simply
>   blocking?

I think that really depends on *what* you're testing. If you look at it from the unit test frameworks point of view, then I don't see any benefit here. I don't think such a framework needs to scale with respect to IO. The only thing that you are doing is testing how your async API's behave. For example, as a library author, you could have an async endpoint and test what happens when your code is synchronously blocked by a caller which doesn't understand how to consume your library properly.

One example could be:

```
[TestClass]
public class M
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void X()
    {
        var myService = new MyService();
        myService.FetchSomeDataAsync().Result; // Will this deadlock?
    }
}
```

Comment: If this can be Deadlock, then it can as well have same disadvantage in Async mode, where though main thread is free but Async operation is locked and waiting, till it is released via an alternate mechanism

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I didn't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I was replying to the comment in your answer - // Will this deadlock?, if Yes, then it would pose a similar issue in Async mode, sans the main thread being free to run other tests